# Minimizing sum of reciprocal of quadratic functions

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Given a set of constants $a_1,\ldots,a_n$, I want to solve the following single-variable optimization problem:

$$\min_x \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i^2}{x(2a_i-x)}, \quad s.t. \quad 0\leq x \leq 2a_i, \forall i$$

I initially thought it is only a single-variable problem so should be easy to solve...
I set the derivative to zero and got to the point where
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{a_i^2}{x^2(2a_i-x)} = \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{a_i^2}{x(2a_i-x)^2}$$
then got stuck.

I also tried a few instances on https://www.wolframalpha.com and saw that a minimizer seems to exist.

Any insight into solving the problem is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The derivative $f'(x)$ is a rational function thus a quotient of two coprime polynomials  $f'(x) = u(x)/v(x)$ and the extremum of $f(x)$ occur at one of the $\deg(u) \le 2n$ roots of $u(x)$.

Comment: @reuns Got it, thanks.

Comment: @reuns If all the coefficients are strictly greater than 0, is there any way to show that the minimizer is unique?